# How a mobile user can upload images using some 3rd party service authorised by our backend

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, mobile, backend

We are building a system (Mobile app. and a serving backend-API).

We want to allow the user on the mobile app to upload his profile image, and other types of images at different situations, but we don't want the users to upload the images to the backend server for many reasons; the question is: is there a 3rd party service that allows the mobile users to upload their images (and passing the reference to that image to our server) , where this upload is authorised someway by our backend server.

In this case each time the user wants to load his (or other users' profiles) image and other types of images, he doesn't have to touch our backend.